# How to get iFrame load event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Just to be clear this might be duplication but my requirement is different and I have did lot of research over this to get but I was unable to get it. So here is my question now: I have scenraio like in one of my Page, iFrame is being loaded, over that iFrame I need to bind a click event using jQuery, for that I have tried below code:

```
$j('.ms-dlgFrame').load(function(){
    $j('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('a [title="Browse"]').bind('click', function(){
        console.log('Frame Loaded');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
           console.log('Function Loaded after Timerout');
           $j('.ms-dlgFrame').each(function(){
              $j(this).contents().find('#resultcontent').css('height','200px'); 
              $j(this).contents().find('#MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch').css('height','200px');
           });
        },5000);
   });
});
```

but there was no luck. I could not get the click event fired. Tried lot of tricks to achieve but did not work for me. Any help over how to bind a click event of iFrame element using jQuery would be much appreciated.

Comment: wrap it in `$("#iframeId").load(...`

Comment: Question is updated, but when I do this on my page, I cannot see any log. Also here I have multiple iFrame so I have used here as a class.

Comment: Did you check if the load function is being called? On your code the 'Frame Loaded' is inside the click callback, so maybe the problem is not loading, but binding the click.

Comment: Nope, no console at all. :(